# Assign value from `forEach` without using element array

Tags: java

What's the best way to minimize this code and also remove the need for a element array to assign the variable with the value from inside the `forEach`:

```
    @Override
    public List<User> getModel() {
        List<User> usersModel = new LinkedList<User>();
        IntStream.of(getWidgetCount()).forEach(i -> {
            Widget widget = getWidget(i);
            AuthManagerRow row = (AuthManagerRow) widget;
            User widgetModel = row.getModel();
            final Boolean[] contains = {false};
            usersModel.forEach(user -> {
                if(user.getObjectId().equals(widgetModel.getObjectId())) {
                    contains[0] = true;
                }
            });
            if(!contains[0]) {
                usersModel.add(widgetModel);
            }
        });
        return usersModel;
    }
```

Comment: Just use normal for/each loops: `for (User user : usersModel)`

Comment: `User widgetModel = (((AuthManagerRow) getWidget(i)).getModel();` - save a few lines

Comment: `IntStream.of(int)` returns a stream with a single element. Did you actually mean to use `IntStream.range(0, getWidgetCount())`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<>();
IntStream.of(getWidgetCount())
  .mapToObject(i -> ((AuthManagerRow) getWidget(i)).getModel())
  .forEach(model -> users.putIfAbsent(model.getObjectId(), model));
return new ArrayList<>(users.values());
```

Assuming `User.getObjectId()` returns `Integer`.

Comment: because only the first `User` for the given `ObjectId` should be returned